# Web API service hangs on reading the stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

**Description**: I am modifying the ASP.NET Core Web API service (hosted in Windows Service) that supports resumable file uploads. This works fine and resumes file uploads in many failure conditions except one described below.

**Problem**: When the service is on ther other computer and the client is on mine and I unplug the cable on my computer, the client detects the absence of network while the service hangs on fileSection.FileStream.Read(). Sometimes the service detects the failure in 8 min, sometimes in 20, sometimes never.

I also noticed that after I unplug cable and stop the client, the service becomes stuck at Read() function and the file size is x KB, but when the service finally detects the exception some time later, it writes additional 4 KB to the file. This is weird because I turned off buffering and the buffer size is 2 KB.

**Question**: How to properly detect the absence of network on the service, or timeout properly, or cancel  the request

**The service code**:

```
public static async Task<List<(Guid, string)>> StreamFileAsync(
   this HttpRequest request, DeviceId deviceId, FileTransferInfo transferInfo)
    {
        var boundary = GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType), DefaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync(_cancellationToken);

        if (section != null)
        {
            var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
            var targetPath = transferInfo.FileTempPath;

            try
            {
                using (var outfile = new FileStream(transferInfo.FileTempPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[DefaultCopyBufferSize];
                    int read;

                    while ((read = fileSection.FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) // HANGS HERE
                    {
                        outfile.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        transferInfo.BytesSaved = read + transferInfo.BytesSaved;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

**The client code**:

```
var request = CreateRequest(fileTransferId, boundary, header, footer, filePath, offset, headers, null);

using (Stream formDataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
            formDataStream.ReadTimeout = 60000;

            formDataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header), 0, header.Length);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                for (int i = 0; i < fs.Length - offset;)
                {
                    int k = await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (k > 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        await formDataStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, k);
                    }

                    i = i + k;
                }
            }

            formDataStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
        }

        var uploadingResult = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;



private static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(
        Guid fileTransferId,
        string boundary,
        string header,
        byte[] footer,
        string filePath,
        long offset,
        NameValueCollection headers,
        Dictionary<string, string> postParameters)
    {
        var url = $"{_BaseAddress}v1/ResumableUpload?fileTransferId={fileTransferId}";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"";
        request.UserAgent = "Agent 1.0";
        request.Headers.Add(headers); // custom headers
        request.Timeout = 120000;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 120000;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        request.ContentLength = CalculateContentLength(filePath, offset, header, footer, postParameters, boundary);
        return request;
    }
```

**What I tried**:

1. I added these in into config files:
2. Tried to set timeout on the server

   var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(o => {                     o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);})
3. Used async and non-async Read()
4. Tried with keep alive and without
5. Tried to abort the request when network was restored: request?.Abort();
6. Tried to set formDataStream.ReadTimeout = 60000;

Comment: As it isn't stated for the server; is setting outfile.ReadTimeout not a option?

Comment: this produces an exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
   at System.IO.Stream.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
   at ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not find a better way, I decided to add a timeout to the reading stream and saving it to the file. The good example was posted here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/

```
public static async Task<List<(Guid, string)>> StreamFileAsync(this HttpRequest request, DeviceId deviceId, FileTransferInfo transferInfo)
{
    var boundary = GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType), DefaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);
    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync(_cancellationToken);

    if (section != null)
    {
        var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
        var targetPath = transferInfo.FileTempPath;

        try
        {
            await SaveMyFile(...);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException){...}
        catch (Exception){...}
    }
}

private static async Task SaveMyFile(...)
{
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(myOtherCancellationToken);
        cts.CancelAfter(streamReadTimeoutInMs);
        var myReadTask = StreamFile(transferInfo, fileSection, cts.Token);
        await ExecuteMyTaskWithCancellation(myReadTask, cts.Token);
}


private static async Task<T> ExecuteMyTaskWithCancellation<T>(Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>) s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        {
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return await task;
}

private static async Task<bool> StreamFile(...)
{
        using (var outfile = new FileStream(transferInfo.FileTempPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[DefaultCopyBufferSize];
            int read;

            while ((read = await fileSection.FileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token)) > 0)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

                await outfile.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                transferInfo.BytesSaved = read + transferInfo.BytesSaved;
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```